# Cannot add JSearch to my project

Tags: javascript, frontend, marklogic

I'm trying to use JSearch in my front-end console but I can't do anything since the error that comes is:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'documents' of undefined

I correctly require the package with:

```
var jsearch = require('/MarkLogic/jsearch');
```

querying the database in this way:

```
 var result = jsearch.documents()
    .where(inputURI)
    .result();
```

So from what I've seen online everything should be fine, but still I have problems. Have I done something wrong or forgotten about anything? Thank you!

Comment: Where did you place the jsearch library in your project? What module system are you using?

Comment: I think that the main problem is that I didn't add the jsearch library in my project, but I don't know where to download it from.

Answer (score 3):

JSearch is distributed with MarkLogic Server for execution in server-side logic in MarkLogic 8 and later.

To query from the middle tier in Node.js, you can use the MarkLogic Node.js API (which can be installed by npm as usual). For the documentation, see:

http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/node-dev

MarkLogic doesn't distribute a driver for the browser environment, if that's indicated by "front-end console."

Hoping that helps,

Comment: That's exactly the explanation I was looking for. Since they gave me this project to modify I didn't expect to do huge transformations while now I see that I also need to implement a middle tier that currently is not present.